# Last Month & Year from a Column with Month as Text & Column with Year as Number

Tags: arrays, excel, max, formula

i need a formula to get the last month & year based on two columns: the first one contains month as text and the second one year as number. For instance:

[image]

I need a formula to express the output as `December-2016`
I tried with an array approaching but didn't figured it out.
Thanks!

Comment: It would be easier if you would change the month to an actual data with a custom format of `mmmm`, baring that vba will be better suited, the formula will be long.  Another method would be to make a small table that equates the month text name with the month number then the formula becomes simpler.  But a UDF in vba would still be easier.

Comment: thanks, but none of those options will work for me. maybe a huge if relating a month name to its number but im triying to keep it simple. i already did an array formula that works based on `LARGE`, but it's made to get the last month & year based on criteria, which is not this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work as an array formula by pressing `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`:

```
=TEXT(MAX(DATEVALUE("1 "&(A2:A6&" "&B2:B6))),"mmmm-yyyy")
```

Comment: A non CSE version: `=TEXT(AGGREGATE(14,6,DATEVALUE("1 "&(A2:A6&" "&B2:B6)),1),"mmmm-yyyy")`. Does not require the Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: thanks guys! this is what i was looking for. both formulas work ok!

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,DATE(B2:B6,LOOKUP(A2:A6,{"april";"august";"december";"february";"january";"july";"june";"march";"may";"november";"october";"september"},{4;8;12;2;1;7;6;3;5;11;10;9}),1),1)
```

Then format the cell with the following custom format:

```
mmmm-yyyy
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`{=MAX (DATE (B2:B6,MONTH (DATEVALUE (A2:A6&" 1")),1)) }`